# Does ARCore have a semantic equivalent of ARKit's "guard let planeAnchor"?

Tags: swift, kotlin, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I'd like to know if there's similar semantic construction in `ARCore`/`Kotlin` like the following `guard let` statement in `ARKit`/`Swift`?

```
let anchor: ARAnchor?

guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { 
    print("condition not met")
    return 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a required semantics for ARCore's `planeAnchor` with **Elvis operator** and **safe cast operator**:

```
public class CenterPosePlaneAnchor { ... }

val anchor: Anchor?
val info = "condition not met"

val planeAnchor = anchor as? CenterPosePlaneAnchor ?: return println(info)
```